Kernel of a linear differential operator in the space of polynomials
Consider the differential operator
F = p * D_x + q * D_y,
where  p, q  are polynomials in  Q[x,y],
Q - the field of rational numbers,
D_x, D_y  are partial derivatives on polynomials by x and y respectively,
F : Q[x,y] -> Q[x,y]
is considered as a linear operator on the space Q[x,y] over Q.
Given p and q, how to describe the kernel  Ker(F)  of F ?
(that is the set of solutions of  F(P) = 0  in polynomials).
How to solve of whether Ker(F) = {0} ?
I believe Ker(F) is a sub-space and a sub-algebra in  Q[x,y].
How to find any finite generator set for Ker(F) ?
When the total degree of the domain of F is bounded by m, the problem can be solved by solving a linear system on coefficients (very expensive, though).
But what about the general case?
Any references?
Thanks.
